# How to make 2 id in 1 row on table php

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

Greatings,
I'm new in programming.
I make some php laravel code. I have data like this

```
Id :1, name:aqua 600ml, qty: 5
Id :2, name:aqua 1000ml, qty:9
Id :3, name:liquid 600ml, qty:1
```

I wan't the table like this

```
No | name   | qty 600ml | qty 1000ml
1. | Aqua   | 5.        | 9
2. | Liquid.| 1.        | 0
```

Can anybody help me with the query?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: you should learn how to make tables throw migration:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#introduction

Comment: You can make one column primary another unique or if you want make a composite primary key using those two fields. but eloquent does not support composite key https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

Comment: Are you trying to get data from 2 rows of a mysql query and return it to one row of a table?

Comment: @Jonny yes right

Comment: @OMR, ok I'll check that link, but I'm not using migration because the DB already exist.

Comment: @prafulla thankyou, I'll search for another composite key docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you've that data in php and want to format it.

```
// Your input data 
$arr = [
    ['Id' => 1, 'name' => 'aqua 600ml', 'qty'=> 5], 
    ['Id' => 2, 'name' => 'aqua 1000ml', 'qty'=> 9],
    ['Id' => 3, 'name' => 'liquid 600ml', 'qty'=> 1]
    ];
    
$arrNew = [];
$intCount = 1;
foreach($arr as $data){
    $matches = [];
    preg_match("/(.*) (\d+)ml/",$data['name'],$matches);
    
    if(isset($arrNew[$matches[1]])){
        $arrNew[$matches[1]]['qty_600ml']    += ($matches[2] == 600 ? $data['qty'] : 0);
        $arrNew[$matches[1]]['qty_1000ml']   += ($matches[2] == 1000 ? $data['qty'] : 0);
    }
    else{
        $arrNew[$matches[1]] = [
            'no' => $intCount++,
            'name' => $matches[1],
            'qty_600ml' => ($matches[2] == 600 ? $data['qty'] : 0),
            'qty_1000ml' => ($matches[2] == 1000 ? $data['qty'] : 0)
        ];
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arrNew);

Output:
Array
(
    [aqua] => Array
        (
            [no] => 1
            [name] => aqua
            [qty_600ml] => 5
            [qty_1000ml] => 9
        )

    [liquid] => Array
        (
            [no] => 2
            [name] => liquid
            [qty_600ml] => 1
            [qty_1000ml] => 0
        )

)
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this data. Show in front end table or to store in database. If storing in database then field `no` must not be used.